# Adding 'n' number of collection view to UIStackView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uistackview

I have a `ViewController` Class where I'm putting `scrollView` and adding `stackView` as the subview. Now I want to add 'n' number of `collectionView` inside the `stackView`. I'm fetching data from server, there will be a different categories. If category A has data, then I need to create one `collectionView` for that. And I need to handle the data of corresponding `collectionView` in their class itself.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var scrollView : UIScrollView!
var stackView : UIStackView!
var responseFullData : JsonFullDataResponse!
var responseData : JsonResponse!

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    print("View Controller init")
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("View did appear")
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackView.frame.width, height: stackView.frame.height)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //loading all the data
    loadAllJsonData()

    //setting up scroll and stack views
    setUpScrollAndStackView()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("inside layout")
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackView.frame.width, height: stackView.frame.height)
}

func setUpScrollAndStackView() {
    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView]|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))

    stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.spacing = 20.0
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)


  scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
  scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[stackView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))

    setUpOtherViewsInStack()
}

func setUpOtherViewsInStack() {
    if responseFullData.banner?.count != 0 {
        print("banner has data")

        var bannerCollection : BannerCollectionView = BannerCollectionView() as! BannerCollectionView
        bannerCollection.register(UINib.init(nibName: "BannerCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BannerCell")
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(bannerCollection)
   }
}
```

**BannerCollectionView Code**

```
class BannerCollectionView: UICollectionView , UICollectionViewDataSource{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        print("control is in datasource")
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BannerCell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
}
```

How do I make this work. In which class and where I should set the `delegate` and `datasource` property of `BannerCollectionView`? How do I initialise this?

Comment: try adding bannerCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false before adding in the StackView

Comment: A question, You need to add a number of collectionViews inside of your UIStackView = responseFullData.banner?.count ??

Comment: No . ResponseFullData has 5 arrays like banner , menu, items etc. I’m checking whether the count of each array is not 0 and then add collection view for each array to display there items . Did you get my point ?

Comment: Is ResponseFullData a dictionary? and which are the keys for the others  arrays?

Comment: class JsonFullDataResponse : HandyJSON {
    
    var banner : [Banner]?
    var menuData : [MenuData]?                                                            var selectedGoods : [SelectedGoods]?
    var merchants : [Merchants]?
    var bestSelling : [BestSelling]?
    var marketing : [Marketing]?

Comment: So I want to add collectionview for each of item, If it has count. So I need to handle this in different class collectionViews like BannerCollectionView: UICollectionView , MenuCollectionView : UICollectionView.

Comment: so In which class and where I should set the delegate and datasource property of BannerCollectionView? How do I initialise this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added 3 collectionView inside the UIStackView(Vertical stack). The whole view can be scrolled vertically and the collection items can be scrolled either horizontally or vertically.

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController,HeaderViewDelegate {

var scrollView : UIScrollView!
var stackView : UIStackView!
var responseFullData : JsonFullDataResponse!

if responseFullData?.menu?.count != nil{
        print("menu has data")

        var menuCollection : MenuCollectionView = MenuCollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
        menuCollection.backgroundColor = .white
        menuCollection.menuData = (self.responseFullData.menu)!
        menuCollection.dataSource = menuCollection.self
        menuCollection.delegate = menuCollection.self
        createCollectionViews(collectionViewClass: menuCollection, identifier: "MenuCell",height : 175)
    }
    if responseFullData?.hongbei?.count != nil {
        print("hongbei has data")
        var hongbeiCollection : HongbeiCollectionView = HongbeiCollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())

        hongbeiCollection.dataSource = hongbeiCollection
        hongbeiCollection.delegate = hongbeiCollection
        hongbeiCollection.allowsSelection = true
        hongbeiCollection.backgroundColor = .white
        hongbeiCollection.hongbeiData = (self.responseFullData.hongbei)!


        addHeaderView(headerTitle : "Hongbei")
        createCollectionViews(collectionViewClass: hongbeiCollection, identifier: "HongbeiCell",height : 150)

    }
    if responseFullData?.freeZone?.count != nil {
        print("freezone has data")
        var freezoneCollection : FreeZoneCollectionView = FreeZoneCollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
        freezoneCollection.dataSource = freezoneCollection.self
        freezoneCollection.delegate = freezoneCollection.self
        freezoneCollection.backgroundColor = .white
        freezoneCollection.freeZoneData = (self.responseFullData.freeZone)!
        addHeaderView(headerTitle : "FreeZone")
        createCollectionViews(collectionViewClass: freezoneCollection, identifier: "FreeZoneCell",height : 150)
    }

func createCollectionViews(collectionViewClass : UICollectionView, identifier : String,height : CGFloat ){

    collectionViewClass.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
    collectionViewClass.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    collectionViewClass.register(UINib.init(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    collectionViewClass.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionViewClass.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(collectionViewClass)

}

 func addHeaderView(headerTitle : String){
    let headerView = HeaderView.instanceFromNib() as! HeaderView
    headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
    headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    headerView.headerLabel.text = headerTitle
    headerView.frame = headerView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 20, dy: 0)
    headerView.delegate = self
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(headerView)

}
```

}

```
class MenuCollectionView: UICollectionView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var menuData : [MenuData]!

override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

}

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    print("Menu")
    return menuData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    cell.menuLabel.text = menuData[indexPath.item].title!

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width * 0.175), height: 75)
}
```

I have a separate class for each collectionView in the stack, where I handle the data source and delegate methods. So I can have any number for collection items I want in each collectionView.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to make a **for** from 0 to count in `responseFullData.banner.count` adding a collectionView each time

```
if let count = responseFullData.banner?.count {
    for i in 0..<count {
        var bannerCollection : BannerCollectionView = BannerCollectionView() as! BannerCollectionView
        bannerCollection.register(UINib.init(nibName: "BannerCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BannerCell")
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(bannerCollection)
    }
}
```